# Can someone explain to me the Google DFP infinite scroll example and why/if disableInitialLoad and refresh are absolutely needed

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

I was looking at the "Implementing tags on pages with infinite contents" example on https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/4578089?hl=en.  I noticed that this code uses googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad(); and then requires both googletag.display(slotName); and googletag.pubads().refresh([slot]); to actually display the ad.

My question is, why do we have to do it this way where we call display and refresh.  What is wrong with not using googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad(); and then just calling googletag.display(slotName); to display the additional loaded ads?

I tested it out commenting out the disableinitialload and the refresh and it works. You can see the code here http://jsbin.com/yodogejiku/edit?html,output

I just want to know the technical differences between the two and the benefits of choosing one over the other.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think the documentation of that feature is not excellent and your approach is better.